# Deploying code via git push is broken

Tags: git

I have deployed a Git application on OpenShift. Until now I was using `git push` command, which was automatically pushing the new code to remote repository as well as building and deploying the code through Maven.

But yesterday I was trying out Jenkins, so I added a Jenkins cartridge to my application. `git push` was changed to build through Jenkins. Since I didn't want to go though details for building through Jenkins, I removed that cartridge.

But now my `git push` command is not working.

It's giving the following message:

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

git config --global push.default simple

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Everything up-to-date
```

How can I get my application to deploy again with `git push`?

Comment: as @corey112358 mentions, this has nothing to do with OpenShift and it has nothing to do with Jenkins. this is a purely Git-based error.

Answer (score 2):

What isn't working?  Looks like you updated your local git installation and are now getting this warning about the default way in which git push works.  Read the directions given there and follow them to get rid of the warning message, otherwise it looks like it works fine.